# How can I get xml argument value in same xml file?

Tags: xml

My file is like this:

```
<argument name="a" value=1>
<argument name="b" value=(there I want to get the value of "a")>
```

how can I get this?

Comment: In which language are you processing this XML?

Comment: Why do you want same value for both `a` & `b`?

Comment: I just want to use the value of "a", it's only one case. but I don't know how to get the value in xml , I think it not relate to language